# Calculating the electric potential of a fruit battery

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrochemistry

In a fruit battery, if I am using a reactive metal electrode for the cathode but the cathode reaction is the reduction of the hydrogen ions (in the acid of the fruit), how can the type of the cathode metal affect the voltage. In my experiment I used the same metal for the anode and different metals for the cathode and the resulting voltages are different. I am confused because the resulting voltage should be the difference between the anode reaction and the cathode reaction which I expected to be the same.

Comment: Give us information about the metal used both for the cathode and the anode. The effect could be entirely different if you choose copper or zinc, or any other metal.

Comment: Narrowing «fruit battery» to «lemon battery», there seems to be a *correlation* between concentration of lemon acid (which depends e.g., by the variety of the lemon tested) and the voltage recorded (figs 3 and 4 of *Construction and evaluation of electrical properties of a lemon battery* by Mazumder et al. in *Journal of Chemical, Biological and Physical Sciences*, **2018**, 92-101, e.g. found on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324744104_Construction_and_evaluation_of_electrical_properties_of_a_lemon_battery).)

Comment: (+1) For a lemon cell (aka “battery”), with zinc anode and copper cathode, the open circuit voltage is different than if you use zinc anode and silver cathode. I did this myself and was puzzled because I thought, as apparently you did as well, that the cathode reduction only involved hydrogen ions being reduced to hydrogen gas. But I think there may be an over-voltage effect that accounts for the difference in open circuit voltages. In any event, good observation!

Comment: I think this Wikipedia article is quite useful here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery